# Any way in WPF to add a top margin SpellCheck squiggle in textBox?

Tags: wpf, margin, spell-checking

Hi I have enabled spellcheck in my WPF TextBox like so:

```
<TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Width="200"  />
```

I would like to add a small top margin to the squiggle decoration.

Is this possible?

(btw. is this possible for any textdecoration in wpf like say underline in a textblock?)

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know fancy inlines / effects over substrings (like the one you are asking) are difficult to achieve in simple TextBox. For them you can use RichTextBox. But you can think of using TextBox's adorner layer smartly... but thats just I would think to do at first.

Comment: Hi AngelWPF, is there a simple way to do this with a RichTextBox? Would it be possible to provide a snippet? Thanks.